# Agregar datos de un data frame dados las coincidencia con elementos en otro data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Tengo un data frame de servicios de bicicleta  donde la estanción de origen y destino están dadas por las columnas:

```
Origen_Id Destino_Id #data frame A
2             52
93            10
```

Etc, en otro .csv tengo el id de las estaciones, nombre de las estaciones, latitud y longitud, es decir, algo así

```
Id Nombre Longitud Latitud
2  Nombre1 20.666378 -103.34882
3  Nombre2 20.667228 -103.366
4  Nombre3 20.66769  -103.368252
```

Quisiera agregar al data frame A columnas con las correspondientes coordenadas según la estación donde iniciaron y llegaron.
Trate de hacerlo con un ciclo for, pero al ser una base muy grande tarda demasiado,¿hay alguna forma de hacerlo más eficiente?

Es decir, me gustaría que fila se viera como,

```
Origen_Id Destino_Id Lon_Orig    Lat_Orig
2             52     20.666378  -103.34882
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es hacer un **join** entre tus bases

Puedes hacer un cruce **left**, para mantener las filas de tu df original

```
merge(df, df2, by.x = "Origen_Id", by.y = "Id",all.x = T)

#  Origen_Id Destino_Id  Nombre Longitud   Latitud
#         2         93 Nombre1 20.66638 -103.3488
#        52         10    <NA>       NA        NA
```

O un cruce **inner** para quedarte solo con los id que encuentre en la df2

```
merge(df, df2, by.x = "Origen_Id", by.y = "Id",all = F)

#  Origen_Id Destino_Id  Nombre Longitud   Latitud
#          2         93 Nombre1 20.66638 -103.3488
```

Trabajando con tidyverse puedes llegar a los mismos resultados usando:

```
left_join(df, df2 , by = c("Origen_Id" = "Id"))

inner_join(df, df2 , by = c("Origen_Id" = "Id"))
```

Puedes revisar **[esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)** respuesta para mas detalles